# Unity 5.6 - Compilation Error with UWP using Facebook SDK for Windows

Tags: unity, c#, windows, facebook

I built my unity game for UWP and I added winsdkfb to authenticate user with facebook ID. When I build my project in visual studio 2017, it throws an error which is:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   The command ""C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n
>   Jump\Build\W10\Unity\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe" -platform=uap
>   -lock="C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n Jump\Build\W10\Kukku Free\project.lock.json" -bits=32 -configuration=Master
>   -removeDebuggableAttribute=True -uwpsdk=10.0.15063.0 -path="." -path="D:\Unity5.6\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\MetroSupport\Players\UAP\dotnet\x86\Master"
>   "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n Jump\Build\W10\Kukku
>   Free\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n
>   Jump\Build\W10\Kukku Free\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll"
>   "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n Jump\Build\W10\Kukku
>   Free\UnityEngine.dll" "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n
>   Jump\Build\W10\Kukku Free\Facebook.Unity.Settings.dll"
>   "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n Jump\Build\W10\Kukku
>   Free\nunit.framework.dll" "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n
>   Jump\Build\W10\Kukku Free\GameSparks.dll"
>   "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n Jump\Build\W10\Kukku
>   Free\UnityEngine.UI.dll" "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n
>   Jump\Build\W10\Kukku Free\GameSparks.Api.dll"
>   "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n Jump\Build\W10\Kukku
>   Free\UnityEngine.Networking.dll" "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n
>   Jump\Build\W10\Kukku Free\Facebook.Unity.dll"
>   "C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n Jump\Build\W10\Kukku
>   Free\GameSparksRT.dll"" exited with code 1. Kukku Free
>   C:\Users\saada\Documents\Tap n Jump\Build\W10\Kukku Free\Kukku
>   Free.csproj 321

When I remove my code which involves facebook authentication, it builds and runs fine. I googled it but didn't find any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this post I assume is quite old but this bug had me for a while so I figured I would pay it forward.

You are getting an exception because Unity is using Mono.Cecil to try to weave all your compiled assemblies. It every one in the error above and also every assembly it references. If it can't find one of these assemblies you get this exception. The issue is the winsdkfb project is not going to be found.

Fix:
Copy the output of the compiled winsdkfb into the folder `[Generated Project Path]\[project name]\[Project Name]\`. You will know it's the correct folder because you will see all the dlls mentioned in the error above.

Cheers,